Prove that $\Sigma_A(\overline A)\leq\operatorname{hd}(A,\overline A)\leq\operatorname{md}(A, \overline A)$.
Let $A\in \mathbb C^{n,n}$ and perturbed matrix $\overline{A}\in \mathbb C^{n,n}.$ Suppose spectrum of A, $\sigma(A)=\{ \lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n\}$  and $\sigma(\overline A)=\{ \overline\lambda_1,\overline\lambda_2,...,\overline\lambda_n\}.$
Spectral variation of $\overline A$ with respect to $A$ given by
$$\Sigma_A(\overline A)=\max_i\min _j |\overline \lambda_i-\lambda_j|.$$
Hausdorff distance between the spectrum is defined as the $\operatorname{hd}(\overline A,A)=\max\{\Sigma_A(\overline A),\Sigma_{\overline A}(A)\}.$

Prove that $\Sigma_A(\overline A)\leq\operatorname{hd}(A,\overline A)\leq\operatorname{md}(A, \overline A).$

What do you mean by optimal pair distance?
It is defined as
$$\operatorname{md}(A, \overline A)= \min_{\Pi\in S_n}\max_i |\overline \lambda_{\Pi(i)}-\lambda_i|$$
where $S_n$ is the set of all permutation of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}.$
I don't understand this definition properly.
My attempt to understand the definition:-
We know that $S_n$ has $n!$ elements. Let elements are written like this $\Pi_1, \Pi_2,...,\Pi_{n!}$
$$\operatorname{md}(A, \overline A)= \min_{\Pi_1,\Pi_2,...,\Pi_{n!}}(\max_i |\overline \lambda_{\Pi_k(i)}-\lambda_i|)$$
$$\operatorname{md}(A, \overline A)= \min_{k=1,2,3,...,n!}(\max\{|\overline \lambda_{\Pi_k(1)}-\lambda_1|,|\overline \lambda_{\Pi_k(2)}-\lambda_2|,...,|\overline \lambda_{\Pi_k(n)}-\lambda_n|\})$$
Still, I don't understand what that means. How is it related to the Haursdorf distance? It is given that.
$\Sigma_A(\overline A)\leq\operatorname{hd}(A,\overline A)\leq\operatorname{md}(A, \overline A).$
Please help me to understand the definition and prove the inequality.
One inequality is evident from the definition of Hausdorff distance.
$\Sigma_A(\overline A)\leq\operatorname{hd}(A,\overline A)$
I don't know how to prove the other inequality.
Please help me to understand the definition and complete the inequality.

I have never seen these concepts before, so I unfortunately cannot help you with an interpretation, however I can help you with how to prove the inequality.
We show first that
$$\Sigma_A(\bar{A})\leq\mathrm{md}(A,\bar A).$$
To show this, we first show that
$$\min_j\lvert\bar{\lambda}_i-\lambda_j\rvert\leq\max_j\lvert\bar\lambda_{\Pi(j)}-\lambda_j\rvert$$
for all $i$ and all $\Pi\in S_n$. So fix $i$ and $\Pi\in S_n$. Let $k=\Pi^{-1}(i)$, and observe that then
$$\max_j\lvert\bar\lambda_{\Pi(j)}-\lambda_j\rvert\geq\lvert\bar\lambda_{\Pi(k)}-\lambda_k\rvert=\lvert\bar\lambda_{i}-\lambda_k\rvert\geq\min_j\lvert\bar\lambda_i-\lambda_j\rvert.$$
The inequality follows. Our first inequality now follows by simply taking maximum over $i$ and minimum over $\Pi\in S_n$. An identical argument shows that
$$\Sigma_{\bar A}(A)\leq\mathrm{md}(A,\bar A).$$
Consequently
$$\mathrm{hd}(A,\bar A)=\max\{\Sigma_{A}(\bar A),\Sigma_{\bar A}(A)\}\leq\mathrm{md}(A,\bar A).$$
The result follows.
